Getting an AuthorizationError after trying to access h01 dataset using cloudvolume in Google Colab
I have been trying to access the h01 human brain dataset with instructions in Google Colab.
Cell 1


# Install cloud-volume to access h01 mesh and skeleton data.
# You may need to restart the runtime after installing.
!pip install cloud-volume

Here is where I am getting an error:
Cell 2
import cloudvolume
import google.colab.auth
google.colab.auth.authenticate_user()

This is the exact Error I'm getting:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AuthorizationError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-ce0a987c6451> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import cloudvolume
      2 import google.colab.auth
----> 3 google.colab.auth.authenticate_user()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/auth.py in authenticate_user(clear_output, project_id)
    300   if _check_adc(_CredentialType.USER):
    301     return
--> 302   raise _errors.AuthorizationError('Failed to fetch user credentials')
    303 
    304 

AuthorizationError: Failed to fetch user credentials

With this warning repeated a bunch of times:
WARNING:google.auth.compute_engine._metadata:Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable on attempt 1 of 5. Reason: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Is the issue on my end on theirs? And how do I go about fixing this?
I have tried restarting the runtime as suggested but to no avail.
Here is the Google Colab link in question
